# Selenium Python UnboundLocalError: local variable 'element' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a span tag which contains the text "Clean feed crm"
using an XPATH locator.
I get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'element' referenced before assignment
```

Full error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\OperationsPage_TestCase.py", line 56, in test_add_and_run_clean_process
    process_lists_page.click_clean_feed_task_from_groups_tab(Globals.process_lists_clean_feed_task_crm)
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\operations.py", line 90, in click_clean_feed_task_from_groups_tab
    clean_feed_crm_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks"]//../span[contains(text(), "Clean feed crm")]')
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\Pages\base.py", line 31, in get_element
    return element
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'element' referenced before assignment
```

If i use the absolute full XPATH it works fine.  The relative XPATH it shows the error.

The full absolute XPATH which works is:

```
(By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[1]/span')
```

The relative XPATH which does not work is:

```
(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks"]//../span[contains(text(), "Clean feed crm")]')
```

The HTML is:

```
    <div id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks" class="GPI5XK1CDG" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true" role="tree">
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
    <div>
    <div aria-selected="false" role="treeitem" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="1" aria-expanded="true" aria-level="1">
    <div class="GPI5XK1CIF GPI5XK1CAG" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
    <div>
    <div aria-selected="false" role="treeitem" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="1" aria-level="2">
    <div class="GPI5XK1CIF" style="padding-left: 16px;">
    <div class="GPI5XK1CIF GPI5XK1CKF" style="padding-left: 16px;position:relative;" onclick="">
    <div style="position:absolute;display:none;"/>
    <div class="GPI5XK1CLF">
    <div style="padding-left: 22px;position:relative;zoom:1;">
    <div style="left:0px;margin-top:-8px;position:absolute;top:50%;line-height:0px;">
    <img border="0" style="width:16px;height:16px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0px 0px;" src="http://justin-pc.infoshare.local:8080/clearcore501/ClearCore/clear.cache.gif" onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent="load";"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>
            <span class=" myinlineblock" title="Clean feed crm" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;width:100%;margin-right:-14px;">Clean feed crm</span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <span class="" title="Turn task off or on." style="">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" tabindex="-1"/>
        </span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div aria-selected="false" role="treeitem" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="2" aria-level="2">
    <div class="GPI5XK1CIF" style="padding-left: 16px;">
    <div class="GPI5XK1CIF GPI5XK1CKF" style="padding-left: 16px;position:relative;" onclick="">
    <div style="position:absolute;display:none;"/>
    <div class="GPI5XK1CLF">
    <div style="padding-left: 22px;position:relative;zoom:1;">
        <div style="left:0px;margin-top:-8px;position:absolute;top:50%;line-height:0px;">
            <img border="0" style="width:16px;height:16px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0px 0px;" src="http://justin-pc.infoshare.local:8080/clearcore501/ClearCore/clear.cache.gif" onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent="load";"/>
        </div>
    <div>
        <span>
            <span class=" myinlineblock" title="Clean feed escr" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;width:100%;margin-right:-14px;">Clean feed escr</span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span class="" title="Turn task off or on." style="">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" tabindex="-1"/>
        </span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My method implementation is:

```
def click_clean_feed_task_from_groups_tab(self, feed):
        # Params: feed: clean feed crm, clean feed escr or clean feed orchard
        #clean_feed_crm_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="myinlineblock" and contains(text(), "%s") % feed]')            
        clean_feed_crm_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks"]//../span[contains(text(), "Clean feed crm")]')
        #clean_feed_crm_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks"]//..//.//..//..//..//..//..//..//../span[contains(text(), "%s")] % feed ]')))     
        clean_feed_crm_element.click()
        return self
```

From my TestCase class i call th method:

```
    project_navigator = ProjectNavigatorPage(self.driver)
    process_lists_page = project_navigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Process Lists")
    process_lists_page.click_add_button_for_process_lists()
    process_lists_page.click_clean_task_arrow_to_expand_it_from_groups_tab("add")
    process_lists_page.click_clean_feed_task_from_groups_tab(Globals.process_lists_clean_feed_task_crm)
```

Globals.py is:

```
process_lists_clean_feed_task_crm = "Clean feed crm"
```

I havea also tried using WebDriverWait still the same error:

```
clean_feed_crm_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks"]//../span[contains(text(), "%s") % feed]')))
```

%s, % feed the value is "Clean feed crm" as I am looking for this text (passed in as a parameter into my method.

What am i doing wrong?  What XPATH could i use then to click the element which has the text "Clean feed crm"?

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we recall some elements from the XPath sintax:

- The expression "//" selects nodes in the document from the current
  node that match the selection no matter where they are.
- The expression ".." selects the parent of the current node.

Therefore when you write:

```
//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks"]//..
```

You are selecting the div node itself. From that node the relative XPath should be:

```
//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_ct_groups_and_tasks"]//span[contains(text(), "Clean feed crm")]
```

That way you select the div node with the id selected, and look inside for the span tag which contains the text.

Comment: This works and i understand what the // and .. does now.  Thank you.